# How clean data in two columns of a csv file, with many rows as documents

Tags: tm, data-cleaning, stop-words

I need to clean textual data from two columns (say c(8,9)) of a cvs file with around 800 rows, where each row represent a different document, containing comments from interviewees on a company. I need to apply the stopwords, but I don't know how to use tm functions on those rows of these two columns.

```
library(tm)
setwd("C:\\temp")
netf <- read.csv2("netflix.csv")
corp <-tm_map(netf, c(8,9), removeWords, stopwords("english"))
```

> Error in UseMethod("tm_map",x):
>   no applicable method for "tm_map" applied to an object of class "data.frame"

I would like to get the two columns with their 800 rows cleaned by stopwords